# SQL Query issue with Northwind Sample database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently playing with the Northwind Sample database that ships with SQL Server. I am trying to write a query for finding "Customers who has spent more than $25,000 in orders with Northwind". In the same context I have written the following query:

```
select a.customerid, sum (b.unitprice*b.quantity) as Total_Amount
from orders a join [order details] b on a.orderid=b.orderid
--where Total_Amount > 25000  --ERROR: In this filter condition, SQL Server is not recongnizing "Total_Amount"
group by a.customerid
order by Total_Amount desc
```

The query seems to be working correctly except for the fact that I am unable to put the filter condition (of 25000, pls refer to the commented line in the query) as it seems SQL Server does not recognize alias names (i.e.,Total_Amount), in the filter condition. However it is recognizing the alias in the Order By clause.

Pls help me with the right approach to this query and what would be the possible work arounds?

Thanks,
XM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * FROM (
select a.customerid, sum (b.unitprice*b.quantity) as Total_Amount
from orders a join [order details] b on a.orderid=b.orderid
--where Total_Amount > 25000  --ERROR: In this filter condition, SQL Server is not recongnizing "Total_Amount"
group by a.customerid
) as a
WHERE a.Total_Amount > 25000
order by Total_Amount desc
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
select a.customerid, sum (b.unitprice*b.quantity) as Total_Amount
from orders a join [order details] b on a.orderid=b.orderid
group by a.customerid
having sum (b.unitprice*b.quantity) > 25000
order by sum(b.unitprice*b.quantity) desc
```

Also, try *having* a look at [the Having clause documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use aliases in the WHERE clause.

As SUM is an aggregate function you would need to move it to the HAVING clause.

It's to do with the order in which the query is executed(the Logical Query Processing Phase) there is a detailed article on this [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/).

```
SELECT a.customerid, sum (b.unitprice*b.quantity) as Total_Amount 
FROM orders a join [order details] b on a.orderid=b.orderid 
GROUP BY a.customerid 
HAVING SUM(b.unitprice*b.quantity) > 25000  
ORDER BY Total_Amount desc
```